# jQuery simple clone plugin - change input name format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using simple clone plugin. This is the [github page](https://github.com/pake007/simple-clone) of that plugin.

As of now it generates input name like

```
user[projects][0][name]
user[projects][1][name]
user[projects][2][name]
```

Can anyone tell me how to generate name like

```
user[projects_name][0][1]
user[projects_name][1][1]
user[projects_name][2][1]
```

I have created a `jsfiddle` to show you demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/YLSdQ/1/

I think this is the function that generates the id.

```
// append a initial number to elements id, if options[:nested] true, also assign a initial number to the element name
  e.find("input, select").each(function(){
    var old_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).attr("id", old_id+'_0');
    if(option.nested == true) {
      var old_name = $(this).attr("name");
      var reg = /\[\w*\]$/;
      var match = reg.exec(old_name);
      var new_name = old_name.substr(0, match.index) + "[0]" + match[0];
      $(this).attr("name", new_name);
    }
  })
$.fn.regenerate_names = function(number){
    $(this).find("input, select").each(function(){
      var old_name = $(this).attr("name");
      var old_number = old_name.match(/.*\[(\d+)\]/)[1];  // find the last match
      var old_number_index = old_name.lastIndexOf(old_number);
      var new_name = old_name.substring(0,old_number_index) + number + old_name.substring(old_number_index+1);
      $(this).attr("name", new_name);
    });
  };
```

Here is the [full source code](https://github.com/pake007/simple-clone/blob/master/simpleclone.js#L47)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pake007, the author of the plugin. I have updated the plugin to support your requirement.
Please clone the newest version of simple-clone on github, and for your question, I think you can try the following code:

```
<div class='project_group'>
  <input id="user_projects_name" name="user[projects_name][1]" type="text" /> 
</div>

$(".project_group").simple_clone({
  label: "Project Name ",
  label_colon: true,
  nested: true,
  start: 1
});
```

The new option "start" is used for setting the start of the first array index in the input name, default is 0.

The above code will generate input names like:

```
user[projects_name][1][1]
user[projects_name][2][1]
user[projects_name][3][1]
```